# binding.pry ignored by rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pry

I'm trying to debug my little app failing to create a Price because of an AssociationTypeMismatch. So I dig out pry, install, watch railscast and Josh's screencast and dig into the wiki.

I "cd" into the prices controller but that fails. I've put <% binding.pry %> into the new.html before the submit code but Rails says that the 'pry' method is unknown. pry is in my updated Gemfile and I restarted the server.

I put binding.pry into the create method of my prices_controller.rb and Rails happily breezes through it to throw the error I've already seen, not the pause, etc I was expecting.

Looking at the Price model, I'm not experienced enough to know what I should be looking for. What am I overlooking? thanx, sam

Comment: Did you run bundle install after updating your Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in addition to the pry gem, I need the pry-rails gem as well. Now the binding.pry is recognized.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same problem, my solution was to add **pry-remote** to my Gemfile, and call **binding.remote_pry** instead of **binding.pry**, open the terminal at your current project and execute **pry-remote**. happy debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing pry-rails you could just `require 'pry'` before the binding :-)